# How to convert Geometry type column to degree Minutes Second in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: convert, sql, sql-server, geometry, degrees-minutes-seconds

I have shape column of type geometry and I want to convert X and Y coordinates into Degree Minutes Second format using SQL query and i am using sql server 2008 R2.

Currently I got Lat and long using this query

```
Select W.SHAPE.STY as latitude, W.SHAPE.STX as longitude from tbdata
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the actual geometry as DMS, or you want to convert the native geometry type to DMS for querying?

Comment: Does the solution can be also used with Geography ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the formula from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees), except that this will truncate fractional seconds because SQL only allows the modulo operator with ints.

```
DECLARE @geom geometry;

SET @geom = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-83.255 32.567477)', 4326);


SELECT CASE WHEN @geom.STX < 0 then '-' ELSE '' END +
    CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STX)) as varchar) + ' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STX) * 60) AS INT) % 60 as varchar) + ''' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STX) * 3600) AS INT) % 60 AS VARCHAR) + '"',
  CASE WHEN @geom.STY < 0 then '-' ELSE '' END +
    CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STY)) as varchar) + ' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STY) * 60) AS INT) % 60 as varchar) + ''' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STY) * 3600) AS INT) % 60 AS VARCHAR) + '"'
```

or for N, S, E, W rather than signs

```
DECLARE @geom geometry;

SET @geom = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-83.255 32.567477)', 4326);


SELECT CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STX)) as varchar) + ' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STX) * 60) AS INT) % 60 as varchar) + ''' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STX) * 3600) AS INT) % 60 AS VARCHAR) + '"' +
    CASE WHEN @geom.STX < 0 then ' W' ELSE ' E' END,
  CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STY)) as varchar) + ' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STY) * 60) AS INT) % 60 as varchar) + ''' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(@geom.STY) * 3600) AS INT) % 60 AS VARCHAR) + '"' +
    CASE WHEN @geom.STY < 0 then ' S' ELSE ' N' END
```

Comment: thanks man but what about **N S E W** value...???

Comment: Remove the "CASE WHEN geom.STX < 0 then '-' ELSE '' END +" at the start and add "+ CASE WHEN geom.STX < 0 then ' W' ELSE ' E' END" at the end.  Similarly for STY < 0 is S otherwise N.  Note ampersand omitted because the comment editor yacked on it.

Comment: Shouldn't this be used with geography rather than geometry ? but geography doesn't have STX....

Comment: @Royi, can use it with either, see Baodad below for using geography.

Answer (score 1):

(Credit to @Russell at ISC for the use of the modulo operator.)
We have a table in SQL Server with a column of geography data type, called [GeoCoor].

This is how we convert to degrees, minutes, and seconds:

```
SELECT
[GeoCoor].[Lat] as [DecimalLatitude],
floor(ABS([GeoCoor].[Lat]))*(CASE WHEN [GeoCoor].[Lat] < 0 then -1 ELSE 1 END) as [LatDegrees],
convert(int,ABS([GeoCoor].[Lat])*60) % 60 as [LatMinutes],
convert(decimal(4,2),convert(decimal(17,10),ABS([GeoCoor].[Lat])*3600) % 60) as [LatSeconds],
[GeoCoor].[Long] as [DecimalLongitude],
floor(ABS([GeoCoor].[Long]))*(CASE WHEN [GeoCoor].[Long] < 0 then -1 ELSE 1 END) as [LongDegrees],
convert(int,ABS([GeoCoor].[Long])*60) % 60 as [LongMinutes],
convert(decimal(4,2),convert(decimal(17,10),ABS([GeoCoor].[Long])*3600) % 60) as [LongSeconds]
FROM SQLTableWithGeographyData
```

This creates separate columns for degrees, minutes, and seconds, which we put together later at the application or report layer.